# Adding a stencil on a black overlay with CSS - Inverted circle mask

Tags: html, css, canvas, opacity

I have an iPhone screenshot (jpeg background) with a black overlay (with some opacity). I need to dynamically add a round stencil with a specific radius that overrides the black background so that it becomes more visible.

By *dynamically* I mean that i must set the x,y coordinates to whatever I need.

**CSS**

```
#img {
    display: block;
    width: 480px;
    height: 720px;
    background: url('iphone.jpg') no-repeat center center
}
div.overlay {
    display: block;
    width: 480px;
    height: 720px;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    -khtml-opacity: 0.65;
    -moz-opacity: 0.65;
    opacity: 0.65;
}
div.stencil {
    /* ??? */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="img">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="stencil"></div>
</div>
```

Here it's an example of what i'm trying to achieve:

[image: iPhone screenshot with black overlay]

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this: http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll show you **2 examples**, with an **DIV as overlay**, and with HTML5 **canvas**.

### DIV overlay:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/agurop/3/edit)**</kbd>

I would suggest to create an big square opaque .png with four 1/4 circle holes at each corner.
Set it as repeated background for the `.overlay`.
Than setting that DIV's `packground-position: Xpx , Ypx;` you'll perfectly target any desired area at the exact center.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="img">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#img {    
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 199px;
    height: 390px;
    background: url('iphone.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}

.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohb0l.png);
    /* PLAY HERE: */
    background-position: 120px 130px;
}
```

[image]

---

### Otherwise use canvas :)

`globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';` will do the trick:

The following code will put a mask over an image and remove an *arc* from the mask:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/agurop/1/edit)**</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="iphone"></canvas>
```

**JS:**

```
var cirsleSize = 30 ,  // circle radius
    circleX = 120 ,    // X pos
    circleY = 130 ;    // Y pos

// ---------------------------------------------

var canvas = document.getElementById('iphone'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image();

canvas.height=390;
canvas.width=199;

img.onload = function() {

   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0)";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   var mask = document.createElement('canvas');
   mask.width = canvas.width;
   mask.height = canvas.height;
   var maskCtx = mask.getContext('2d');
   maskCtx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";
   maskCtx.fillRect(0, 0, mask.width, mask.height);
   maskCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
   maskCtx.arc(circleX, circleY, cirsleSize, 0, 2*Math.PI);
   maskCtx.fill();
   ctx.drawImage(mask,0,0);
      
};

img.src = 'iphone_199x390.jpg';
```

Comment: This'll be a great start. Thanks!

Comment: @Andufo Thanks! (If you don't mind I'll add the `html5` and `canvas` tags to your question for other people to find your Q more easily!) Happy coding!